# Error "no se puede usar como metodo el miembro file no invocable"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un error al intentar convertir un archivo a formato excel el cual al generar el return me aparece el mensaje de error del titulo

Adjunto código

```
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

    //columns
    dt.Columns.Add("ID FORMULARIO", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("MMARCA", typeof(string));


    //rows

    dt.Rows.Add("123141", "marcass");


    // above code loads the data using LINQ with EF (query of table), you can substitute this with any data source.
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
        var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        workSheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
        package.Save();
    }
    stream.Position = 0;

    string excelName = $"BusinessUnit.xlsx";
    // above I define the name of the file using the current datetime.

    return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", excelName); // this will be the actual export.
}
```

muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esta funcion que recibe como parametro un datagridview, recorre sus columnas y filas, guarde el excel en una determinada ubicacion. Puedes modificarlo para tu uso

```
 private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
    {
        //IMPORTANTE
        // DEBEMOS AGREGAR REFERENCIA Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library en COM
        //y poner arriba = using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja_trabajo = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


            
            //hoja_trabajo.get_Range("A1", System.Type.Missing).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 5; //para el ancho de una columna
            //hoja_trabajo.get_Range("A:A", System.Type.Missing).EntireRow.RowHeight = 60; //alto de todas las filas por eso se pone A:A
            //hoja_trabajo.get_Range("A1", System.Type.Missing).EntireRow.RowHeight = 40; //afecta el alto de una fila en este caso Fila A1

            //hace lo mismo de ancho y alto pero en mas filas 
            //Excel.Range er = hoja_trabajo.get_Range("A:A", System.Type.Missing); //aca esta funcion recibe dos celdas que puede ser [1,1] o "A1"                 
            //er.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 35;
            //er.EntireRow.RowHeight = 100;


            //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
            // Cabeceras de las colummnas
            for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                hoja_trabajo.Cells[0 + 1, j + 1] = grd.Columns[j].HeaderText;
            }
            // filas 
            for (int i = 1; i <= grd.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (j == 0) //j es la columna de la grilla, en este caso si columna es 0(primero columna)
                    {
                        //si queremos poner como celda tipo url usamos esto
                        Excel.Range excelCell = hoja_trabajo.get_Range("A" + Convert.ToString(i+1), System.Type.Missing); //B es la columna en el documento excel , i+1 es la fila
                        Excel.Hyperlink miLink = hoja_trabajo.Hyperlinks.Add(excelCell, "http://www.google.com.bo", Type.Missing, "texto 1", "texto 2");
                    }
                    else {
                        //hoja_trabajo.get_Range("F" + Convert.ToString(i + 1), System.Type.Missing).NumberFormat = "@";//con esto evito que me salga un numero 4545E+12 mas formatos aqui http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm

                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        
                    }                      

                   
                }
            }
            libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
            aplicacion.Quit();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Se realizo con exito!","");
    }
```